# How can I stack download panes vertically using JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, pane

I have a method which returns a pane and on that pane are some Buttons and a ProgressBar used to render the progress of a pending download while allowing the user to pause, resume or cancel it:

[image: screenshot of the download manager with one pane showing progress along with pause, resume, cancel controls for managing the download]

My problem is that when whenever I start a new download I want to add a new pane below the last one, stacking them vertically as new downloads are started. However, the logic I've created opens a new pane in the same position as the last one - overlaying it.

How can I make these panes stack?

#### What I've tried

```
package DownloadManager;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressIndicator;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ProgressClass {

    public Pane show( DownloadAction ob,Button pause,Button resume,Button delete,Thread thread) 
    {


        File resumefile = new File("C:\\Users\\kamran ali\\Desktop\\play.png");
        File pausefile = new File("C:\\Users\\kamran ali\\Desktop\\pause1.png");
        File deletefile = new File("C:\\Users\\kamran ali\\Desktop\\delete1.png");


        Image resIcon = new Image(resumefile.toURI().toString());
        Image paseIcon = new Image(pausefile.toURI().toString());
        Image delIcon = new Image(deletefile.toURI().toString());



        ImageView icon0 = new ImageView(resIcon);
        ImageView icon1 = new ImageView(paseIcon);
        ImageView icon2 = new ImageView(delIcon);
        icon0.setFitWidth(10);
        icon0.setFitHeight(10);
        icon1.setFitWidth(10);
        icon1.setFitHeight(10);

        icon2.setFitWidth(10);
        icon2.setFitHeight(10);


         pause  = new Button(null,icon1);
         resume  = new Button(null,icon0);
         delete= new Button(null,icon2);

        pause.setLayoutX(270);
        resume.setLayoutX(300);
        delete.setLayoutX(330);

        pause.setLayoutY(120);
        resume.setLayoutY(120);
        delete.setLayoutY(120);

        pause.setOnAction(e->{
            thread.suspend();
        });

        resume.setOnAction(e->{
            thread.resume();
        });

        ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar(0.0);
        ProgressIndicator pi = new ProgressIndicator(0.0);
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setLayoutX(100);
        label.setLayoutY(80);
        label.setText(ob.getpath());
        pi.setLayoutX(510);
        pi.setLayoutY(80);
        pi.setPrefSize(50, 50);
        pb.setLayoutX(100);
        pb.setLayoutY(100);
        pb.setPrefWidth(400);
        pb.setProgress(0);
        pb.isIndeterminate();
        pb.progressProperty().unbind();
    pi.progressProperty().bind(ob.progressProperty());
        pb.progressProperty().bind(ob.progressProperty());
        Pane pane1 = new Pane();
    pane1.setLayoutY(40);
        pane1.getChildren().addAll(pb,pi,label,pause,resume,delete);
    return pane1;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code currently shown only describes how your "panes" are created - not how *they* are aligned / placed into the parent container/window.

You use **absolute** positioning for the elements of your `ProgressClass` - pane, I guess you do the same on the "outside".

**Fix:** use layout container instead.

In your outer Windows that holds the other elements, add a `javafx.scene.layout.VBox` instead of directly adding the created `ProgressClass`.

Every time you add another `ProgressClass`-Instance, add that to the `javafx.scene.layout.VBox` as child instead - it will automatically stack your individual instances of `ProgressClass`es *vertically*.

---

You might wan't to visit some layouting tutorials to practice using Layout-containers which are more powerfull then placing every element yourself.

See f.e.: [this official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG) and [VBox() (J8)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/VBox.html)